# water simulation missing in final render output

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation

[image: water simulation full bake in pre-render]
[image: final render output]
I am having an issue in getting the water simulation i have created ( see first picture). In the baking process the water shows up in and is seen flowing in the first picture. Now there is motion with the character, which is already baked. Now when I attempt to render the complete animation with the water simulation baked in (see second picture), all i get is the animation of the character movement, what am i missing in getting all of the render?? I tried working with EVEEE and cycles and I get the same result

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pls provide blend file, so we can see all necessary technical settings we need to know. The reason might be that you have checked some objects as "disabled in renders". But since we have no idea what objects that are, because you just showed us one image - we can only guess. so pls improve your question with a blend file. thx for your understanding.

Comment: how do i up;load the blend fil3?

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: the absolute smallest i can get the file down to and this is after getting rid of the character animation, the character, background, textures, and compressing the file within Blender, is 70 MB,I  don't know what else to do at this point

Comment: you can also copy a link to dropbox or whatever cloud service. what you shouldn't do is setting a password on it.

Comment: gotcha. Chris, thank you for your help, based on what you said about settings and thing being disabled in renders, i took a look deeper in my settings, in particular the particle settings, and i had them set to "none" and 0.0 in the viewport settings and none in the render, so once i adjusted those settings, now the render is coming out.